# On the expected distance of two von Mises distributed random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

#### About this thread

I opened a couple of threads [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062140) and at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320021) regarding the following question, but always put in different contexts. Since there has been no satisfactory answer yet, I collected all accumulated results so far and put it in a more general framework.

---

## The Problem

Let $X, Y$ be two independent, centered von Mises distributed random variables on the circle, i.e. that they can be described via the density function

$$f_X(t \mid \kappa) = \frac{e^{\kappa \cos(t)}}{2\pi I_0(\kappa)} \cdot 1_{[-\pi, \pi]}(t) \; ,$$

where

$$I_{\alpha}(z) 
:= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}}{m! \Gamma(m+1+\alpha)} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i\alpha \tau + z \sin{\tau}} d\tau$$

denotes the [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).
Let further

$$\Delta := \min{\big\{ |X_1 - X_2|, \, 2\pi - |X_1 - X_2| \big\}} = \pi - \big||X_1 - X_2| - \pi \big|$$

be their geodesic distance. The pdf for $\Delta$ can be explicitly calculated and yields

$$f_{\Delta}(t \mid \kappa) = \frac{I_0 \left( 2\kappa \cos{\frac{t}{2}} \right)}{\pi I^2_0(\kappa)}  \cdot 1_{[0, \pi]}(t)\; .$$

**Question**:

Can we find a closed expression for
$$\mathbb{E}[\Delta] 
= \frac{1}{\pi I^2_0(\kappa)} \int_0^{\pi} t I_0 \left( 2\kappa \cos{\frac{t}{2}} \right) dt
= \frac{4}{\pi I^2_0(\kappa)} \int_0^{\pi/2} t I_0 \left( 2\kappa \cos{t} \right)dt \quad ?$$

---

## Partial results from previous threads

#### Tackling the integral in the series representation

Plugging in the series expansion representation of $I_0$ leads to

$$\int_0^{\pi} t \cdot I_0 \left( 2\kappa \cos{\frac{t}{2}} \right) dt = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\kappa^m}{m!}\right)^2 \int_0^{\pi} t\cos^{2m}{\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)} dt,$$

which [seemed discouraging first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060103/integration-of-powers-of-trigonometric-function-with-linear-term), but [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel) was able [to deduce this beautiful identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320021/closed-form-of-integration-of-modified-bessel-function-composed-with-trigonometr/320040#320040)

$$ \int_0^\pi t I_0(2\kappa \cos(t/2)) \; dt = \frac{\pi^2}{2} I_0(\kappa)^2 - 4 \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{I_{2r+1}(\kappa)^2}{(2r+1)^2} \; .$$

This led to a [follow-up thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065973/infinite-summation-formula-for-modified-bessel-functions-of-first-kind), aiming to find a closed expression for the sum appearing on the right side of the equation.

#### Tackling the integral in the integral representation

Plugging in the integral representation of $I_0$ leads to

$$\int_0^{\pi} t \cdot I_0 \left( 2\kappa \cos{\frac{t}{2}} \right) dt = 4 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} t e^{2\kappa \cos{t}\sin{\tau}} dt \, d\tau \;$$

which was the actual trigger for this umbrella-thread because I didn't want to open yet another thread each time a new approach seemed somewhat promising.

Using the substitution $u = \cos{t}$ and integration by parts, one can conclude that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} t e^{\alpha\cos{t}} dt = \frac{\pi^2}{8} + \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_0^1 e^{\alpha u} \arccos^2{u} \; du \; ,$$

which looks equally hard to solve, but with [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 4.551](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) one can deduce that

$$\int_0^1 e^{\alpha u} \arccos{u} \; du = \frac{\pi}{2\alpha} \big( I_0(\alpha) + \boldsymbol{L_0}(\alpha) -\alpha\big) \; ,$$

where $\boldsymbol{L_0}$ is the [modified Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), which makes the integral doesn't look ***that*** impossible anymore.

#### Tackling the integral directly

Again [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik mention in 6.519.1](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} J_{2r}(2z \cos{t}) dt = \frac{\pi}{2} J_r^2(z) \; ,$$
where $J_v(z) = i^z I_v(-iz)$, for $v \in \mathbb{N}$. Which [made me question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062140/general-formula-for-integrating-analytic-function-with-linear-term) if that information is already enough to solve the sought integral.

#### Tackling the integral with a Fourier transform

One can exploit the fact that

$$\mathbb{E}[\Delta] = -i\varphi'_{\Delta}(0) 
= \lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \frac{\varphi_{\Delta}(\omega) - \varphi_{\Delta}(-\omega)}{2i\omega} 
= \lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathcal{Im}\left(\varphi_{\Delta}(\omega)\right)}{\omega} \,$$

where

$$\varphi_{\Delta}(\omega) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it\omega}f_{\Delta}(t) dt ,$$

is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of $\Delta$. 
Note, however that by pulling the limit into the integral (e.g. by [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)) we end up with the same integral as above. Hence, this approach can only be useful if one manages to exploit some clever properties of the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).